# MUST and MUST_NOT query in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indexed documents with metadata "User_Id" containing data "A" 
and "B". I'm trying to check documents "A NOT B". I am not able to get the desired output. I am restricted to not use "query string query" and use "NOT" operator.
Doesn't must_not support multi_match?

```
   {
      "from": 0,
      "size": 24,
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "A",
                "fields": ["User_Id"],
                "fuzziness": "AUTO"
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not" :[
             {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "B",
                "fields": ["User_Id"],
                "fuzziness": "AUTO"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the fuzziness auto. This setting allows approximation in the string: a query "AUTO13273" with fuzziness "AUTO" will match AUTO13272 and AUTO13273 since the distance between those two strings is only 1.

See the [fuzziness documentation here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html)